# Does React Native Flatlist re-render upon deletion/insertion/change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This might seem like a dumb question, but I just spent a bunch of hours making a `List` that I now have to add `onUpdate` `onDelete` `onInsert` functions for, and apparently `FlatList` will just check through my data array (provided I extract a key from each item and re-render accordingly. On top of that it apparently provides virtualization.

**So my question is**, if I use a `keyExtractor` and a unique part of my item (say, a user ID) can I dodge writing `onUpdate` `onDelete` `onInsert` and just rely on `FlatList` doing that part for me?

And if I wanted to sync data every 15 seconds, the user would not see a big re-render of the entire list, right?

Comment: It does for listview, so I'm sure flatlist should work the same way. as long as you pass the id's it shouldnt re-render the whole list

Comment: @MattAft Okay - and that's going to avoid the "flashing" of the list too? Where you do a pull-to-refresh and all the data disappears and reappears instead of just adding/deleting the new stuff?

Comment: yeah, mine doesnt disappear. it just adds or removes the changed rows

Comment: @MattAft Awesome, I'll give it a go - thanks!